# save UIObject data in JSON file

Tags: json, actionscript-3, apache-flex

how to create and save a UIComponent information in JSON file? I'm using as3corelib but i'm unable to save object on disk in text file.

```
    var encodedObjectString:String =    com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.encode(zorder.getItemAt(0));
```

Can I save UIObject in JSON  text file?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Looks like some endless recursion. How does the string `zorder.getItemAt(0)` look like?

Comment: zorder.getItem contains UIObject.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your serialization attempt goes via parent link of your UIObject you want to serialize, and then traverses child list encountering the same UIObject. Stack overflow.

In order to make a manual serialization, you need to serialize only part of your object's fields, excluding any and every link to DisplayObjects of any kind (UIObject class included). For this, perhaps it'll be better if you do a `writeExternal()` implementation for your object, perform a serialization via ByteArray, then use it as you want. Or, you can have your UIObject have a dedicated "data to serialize" object as property that will get serialized natively, and will only contain data that you want to serialize.

[Here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/IExternalizable.html) is a manual about externalizable objects.